# Error in initializing ST-Link device. Reason: ST-Link DLL error

Tags: stm32, truestudio

I'm trying to run one of the sample projects from Atollic's Getting Started Youtube tutorial. At the debugging stage, the captioned error shows up. I'm at a loss since my board is connected and the video doesn't mention anything about the hardware configurations.

Comment: Some links to the site you are talking about would help. Do you have the appropriate debugging software installed? The error is self evident as a DLL file error

Comment: This is the video https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Qlue89q-rWU (19-20 min mark) Debugging software as an add-on to Atollic? I don't think so as I'm quite new to micro controller programming. Does the DLL mean I'm missing a file?

Comment: Yes, that's what it means. Try searching for "ST-link.dll" or something similar

Comment: The 'Getting started with the STM32F401 Discovery kit' mentions that 

To start programming, user must:
 Install the preferred Integrated Development Environment (IDE).
 Install the ST-LINK/V2 driver from the ST web site.

The 2nd part is here, it seems 
https://www.st.com/en/development-tools/st-link-v2.html#sw-tools-scroll

But it's a paid one. Isn't the driver package included with the board purchase?

Answer (score 0):

Met the same error, though I'm using a different board (NUCLEO-L452RE). Solved this problem by clicking "ST-Link Update" in "Help" in STM32CubeIDE.